# Turnover Contraint not working in Portfolio Optimization with Portfolio Analytics

Tags: r, optimization, finance, portfolio, r-portfolioanalytics

I am trying to perform a standard portfolio optimization, but with a constraint to how much the final weights of the portfolio are allowed to deviate from a set of initial weights. I do this with the `PortfolioAnalytics` package and the following code is a MWE without any errors.

```
# load packages and data
library(quadprog)
library(PortfolioAnalytics)
data(edhec)
dat <- edhec[,1:4]

# add initial weights to initial portfolio
funds <- c("Convertible Arbitrage" = 0.4, "CTA Global" = 0.3, "Distressed Securities" = 0.2, "Emerging Markets" = 0.1)
init.portf <- portfolio.spec(assets=funds)

# standard constraints & objectives
init.portf <- add.constraint(portfolio=init.portf, type="box", min_w=0, min_sum=0.99, max_sum=1.01)
init.portf <- add.objective(portfolio=init.portf, type="return", name="mean") 
init.portf <- add.objective(portfolio=init.portf, type="risk", name="StdDev")

# TURNOVER CONSTRAINT (MATTER OF THIS THREAD)
init.portf <- add.constraint(portfolio=init.portf, type="turnover", turnover_target=0)

# optimize portfolio
opt.portf <- optimize.portfolio(R=dat, portfolio=init.portf, trace=TRUE, optimize_method="random")

# check the weights of optimized portfolio
print.default(opt.portf$weights)
```

`turnover_target` is `0`, so the output weights should be the same as the input weights `(0.4, 0.3, 0.2, 0.1)` but instead they are equal weighted `(0.25, 0.25, 0.25, 0.25)`. Equal weighted are the default initial weights, so somehow it seems like the initial weights I set up aren't recognized. However looking at the documentation of [add.constraint](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/versions/1.1.0/topics/add.constraint) or [turnover_constraint](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/versions/1.1.0/topics/turnover_constraint) doesn't help much. It kinda look's like everything should be working. They way I define the initial weights matches with the documentation of [portfolio.spec](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/PortfolioAnalytics/versions/1.1.0/topics/portfolio.spec)

Does anyone have an idea why my initial weights are ignored by turnover_constraint?

Comment: `Leverage constraint min_sum and max_sum are restrictive, consider relaxing. e.g. 'full_investment' constraint should be min_sum=0.99 and max_sum=1.01` that's the warning message I get in the optimization step. Have you tried addressing this issue?

Comment: Yes but the optimization runs nonetheless, and as I have already set `min_sum=0.99 and max_sum=1.01` I figured that warning is triggered falsely. It also occurs without any constraints and the most basic optimization.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the turnover constraint of 0 is the problem, as the following code runs (new `turnover_target = 0.1`):

```
pf2 <- portfolio.spec(assets = funds)
pf2 <- add.constraint(pf2,
                      type="box", 
                      min_w = 0,
                      min_sum = 0.99,
                      max_sum = 1.01,
                      min=c(0.35, 0.25, 0.15, 0.05), 
                      max=c(0.45, 0.35, 0.25, 0.15))

pf2 <- add.constraint(portfolio=pf2, type="turnover", turnover_target=0.1)

# optimize portfolio
pf2 <- optimize.portfolio(R=dat, portfolio=pf2, trace=TRUE, optimize_method="random")

# check the weights of optimized portfolio
> print.default(pf2$weights)
Convertible Arbitrage            CTA Global Distressed Securities      Emerging Markets 
                0.350                 0.340                 0.248                 0.062
```